# Determining arithmetic progression using constraints

Tags: equation-solving

I have a list

```
lista={a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9}
```

I'm trying to get the arithmetic progression using `Solve` with the following rules:

```
Solve[a3+a6==34&&a4+a9==50, {a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9}]
```

Is there anything smarter to apply?

Comment: There are conditions missing in order for this to be an arithmetic progression. They should be added to the equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lista = NestList[# + r &, a1, 20 - 1]
Solve[lista[[3]] + lista[[6]] == 34 && 
   lista[[4]] + lista[[9]] == 50, {r, a1}] /. Rule -> Set
novalista = NestList[# + r &, a1, 20 - 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

An arithmetic progression $\{a, a+d, a+2d, ...\}$ is defined by two terms, $a$ and $d$.  So your problem is trivial:

```
Solve[(a + 2 d) + (a + 5 d) == 34 && 
      (a + 3 d) + (a + 8 d) == 50, 
 {a, d}]
```

{{a -> 3, d -> 4}}

lista =  {3, 7, 11, ...}

Answer (score 1):

```
apQ = Equal @@ Differences @ # &;

lista /. Solve[a3 + a6 == 34 && a4 + a9 == 50 && apQ @ lista, lista][[1]]
```

> {3, 7, 11, 15, 19, 23, 27, 31, 35}

```
FindSequenceFunction @ %
```

> -1 + 4 #1 &